# How to a fade to this Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code for a JavaScript slider and was wondering how I could fade the images rather than having them just come up one after another. I would like there to be no jQuery.

```
imgs_array  = [
                "http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg",
                "http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg",
                "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWnEWQ-9qlQAdlD4a5sRYTWAiWblI8NMfw5bBS5buGrPdYoRxbIgQdAUY"
              ];
imgs        = imgs_array.length;

function next(){    
    img     = document.getElementById("slider-img");
    img_id  = img.dataset.sliderId;

    if(img_id != imgs){
        img.src = imgs_array[img_id++];
        img.setAttribute("data-slider-id", img_id++);
    }else{
        img.src = imgs_array[1];
        img.setAttribute("data-slider-id", 1);
    }


}

setInterval(next, 3000);
```

The code for the image is here

```
<img id="slider-img" data-slider-id="1" src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="slide" />
```

Many thanks

Comment: You could use css transitions.

Comment: will be more easy if you use jquery, $('img[data-slider-id=1]').fadeI()

Comment: @NiZa How would I go about doing that?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
imgs_array = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg",
  "http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg",
  "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWnEWQ-9qlQAdlD4a5sRYTWAiWblI8NMfw5bBS5buGrPdYoRxbIgQdAUY"
];
imgs = imgs_array.length;

function next() {
  img = document.getElementById("slider-img");
  img.className = "";

  setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      img_id = img.dataset.sliderId;
      if (img_id != imgs) {
        img.src = imgs_array[img_id++];
        img.setAttribute("data-slider-id", img_id++);
      } else {
        img.src = imgs_array[1];
        img.setAttribute("data-slider-id", 1);
      }
    }, 1);
    img.className = "visible";
  }, 500);

}

setInterval(next, 3000);
```

```css
img {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

img.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img id="slider-img" data-slider-id="1" class="visible" width="600" height="300" src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="slide" />
```